# What does solid-state solubility mean?

Tags: solid-state-physics, terminology, semiconductor-physics

I was trying to understand n-type doping in diamonds. It mentions the low solid-state solubility for higher atomic radius potential dopants like P, As in diamonds. What does it mean?

Comment: That means you can't put many in without them wanting to precipitate into a secondary phase. Just like adding sugar to water, you can only put so much in. If the dopant isn't sitting nicely on a lattice site, it won't be a dopant.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question posed in the title:

Solid state solubility means this: it is possible for atoms of one kind to thermally diffuse into a lattice structure consisting of a different type of atom. In effect, those atoms that are diffusing in are *dissolved* within the structure of the lattice. They will experience a *solubility limit* in that lattice, beyond which the dissolved atoms will segregate out as a new structural *phase* dispersed in zones within that lattice.

Since all these processes are enabled by diffusion, they will obey a rate law that scales exponentially with temperature. Generally, this means greater solubility at higher temperatures and less at lower temperatures. If brought down quickly enough in temperature (a process called *quenching*), the structures formed at the elevated temperature will become frozen into the bulk structure and persist there in a metastable state at the lower temperature.